# Invalid ViewState when using jQuery tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, viewstate, jquery-tabs

I have a fairly simple page with a set of jQuery tabs, the content of some is called via ajax. I also have a search box in the masterpage in my header.

When I open the tabbed page the search box works fine. However once I have clicked on one of the ajax tabs the search box fails to work with an "Invalid Viewstate" yellow screen of death.

I believe this is because the ajax page is replacing the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden input with its own.

How can I stop this behaviour?

UPDATE: I have noticed that the YSOD only appears in IE and Chrome, Firefox doesn't seem to have the same issue. Although how the browser influences the ViewState, I'm not sure.

UPDATE: I've put a cut down version of the site that shows the issue here: http://dropbox.com/s/7wqgjqqdorgp958/stackoverflow.zip

Comment: Are you load balancing across more than one web server?

Comment: No a single server that is actually both webserver and SQL server

Comment: Are you using ViewState?  Can you disable it?

Comment: Also, can you post the entire error message you are receiving?

Comment: Are you using firebug add on in firefox? It should tell you the parts that are messing up

Comment: I am utilizing viewstate so cannot easily disable it without re-writing a lot of code

Comment: I do have firebug but as mentioned oddly I dont get the error with fireox, only IE and Chrome

Comment: I've put the error output here: http://jsfiddle.net/FqzNV/

Comment: @GordonCopestake Are you able to reproduce the error in a trimmed down page? And possibly put that page somewhere to view the JavaScript code and possibly debug what's happening?

Comment: can u show ur jQuery ajax call with which u fill tabs. and search box is inside tab or outer portion!!!

Comment: I've put a cut down version here that shows the issue: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7wqgjqqdorgp958/stackoverflow.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of such behavior is that you getting content of the `ajaxTab.aspx` page asynchronously and paste it into another aspx page. So you getting two instances of hidden fields with `__VIEWSTATE` name and when page posted back to server theirs values are mixing (might depends on how browser process multiple controls with same `name` on submit). To resolve this you can put second tab's content into a frame:

```
 <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
           <li><a href="#tabs-1">Default Tab</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tabs-2">ajax Content</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
           <p>
                To replicate the error:
                <ul>
                     <li>First use the search box top right to search to prove that code is ok</li>
                     <li>Then click the second ajax tab, and search again.</li>
                     <li>N.B. Chrome / IE give a state error, Firefox does not</li>
                </ul>
           </p>
      </div>
      <iframe id="tabs-2" src="ajaxTab.aspx" style="width:100%;" ></iframe>
 </div>
```

Also, I'm not sure but this seems like error in the `Web_UserControls_search` control. In my opinion, `NavBarSearchItemNoSearchItem_OnClick` method must be refactored as below:

```
protected void NavBarSearchItemNoSearchItem_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var searchFieldTbx = NavBarSearchItemNo;
    var navBarSearchCatHiddenField = NavBarSearchCatHiddenField;

    var term = searchFieldTbx != null ? searchFieldTbx.Text : "";

    if (term.Length > 0) //There is actually something in the input box we can work with
    {
        //Response.Redirect(Url.GetUrl("SearchResults", term));
        Response.Redirect(ResolveClientUrl("~/Web/SearchResults.aspx?term=" + term + "&cat=" + navBarSearchCatHiddenField.Value));
    }
}
```

Draw attention that we resolving client url when redirecting to search results page and instead of `navBarSearchCatHiddenField` use `navBarSearchCatHiddenField.Value` as `cat` parameter.

Comment: I don`t think that using an `IFrame` in 2013 is Ok (That`s just IMHO). I think bringing in just the content `div` would be a much more modern solution.

Comment: @EladLachmi I don't think that using of any html tags depends on current year, weather or time of day. If it solving a problem then it can be used. And I don't see any alternative solution if OP have any server control on the `ajaxTab` page which must be processed on server-side.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, suggesting an `IFrame` was also my first instinct, and I do think some tags can become out-dated (as this one has, IMHO). `IFrame` was used for these types of things before `ajax` became a viable option. To me it seems like a step back.

Comment: Yuriy, I think this is the correct solution. I am testing my code.

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy: Guess you are right. An `IFrame` is the only solution for these circumstances.

Comment: I now have to work out how to adjust the height of the iFrame to the size of the content but thats a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you use AJAX to fill the content of the tab. So in this case, content of your tab will be replaced by the new one from ajax and certainly _VIEWSTATE will be replaced. At server, do you use data from ViewState? In the "static tabs", you should prevent them auto reload by using `cache:true`

Comment: Yes, I am using the viewstate data so cannot disable it. I don't understand what you mean by "prevent auto reload by using cache:true" can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that with your ajax call you bring in a complete `ASPX` page. Including the `Form` tag and its `Viewstate`. If you remove the `Form` tag from `ajaxTab.aspx` you will see everything works fine. asp.net does not know how to handle two `Form` tags in one page. Same goes for hidden `Viewstate` fields. You cannot bring in a full aspx page via ajax. Just bring in the content `Div` you want to display and you`ll be good to go.